# Metric for Ingress Route

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, envoyproxy, heptio-contour

I have two Ingress (Contour managing Envoy) host header based routes (among others) where both the routes point to the same service.

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: s1
          servicePort: http
        path: /
  - host: bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: s1
          servicePort: http
        path: /
...
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - foo.com
    - bar.com
    secretName: secret
```

Is there an existing metric (in Kubernetes, Contour, Envoy) to know how many requests are being routed through each of the two rules, i.e., how many requests are hitting `foo.com` and how many are hitting `bar.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Per host metrics is not exposed by envoy for cardinality explosion [issue](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/3351)

So your only option is to explore possibility of  application exposing it as Prometheus metrics.